# Usual Good Muhurtas to start new financial investment or business

Tags: karma, astrology, navrathri

Namaskar,

I have on and off heard multiple times about right times or auspicious times around the year to start a new task or work. **Would it be possible for you to list down at least few of such occasions around the year?** If you could specifically address **period around Navratri**, and tasks related to **financial investment or new business** that'd be helpful.

Dhanyavaad.

Comment: Use any Panjikas/Panchangas. I consult hard copy Panjikas which are used in Bengal. You should consult those which are used in your region. Or else you can check sites like drikpanchang.com. But consulting a hard copy Panjika is much more helpful in my experience. You can plan everything in advance for a whole year with it.

Comment: @Rickross acha. We generally use Thakur ji ka calendar, along with local Pandit ji guidance. Thanks.

Comment: In the Bengali Panjika I use each day of the whole year is reviewed regarding whether it is good for Kraya Vanijya (buying) and Vikraya Vanijya (selling). Also in the starting chapter of the book itself days (of the whole year) which are good for buying or selling are listed so that users can plan in advance. Similarly, we find info regarding good days for various other events like Diksha, planting of tress, travel, marriage and the other Samskaras etc.. So you basically need a similar Panjika the one that is followed in your region. You can ask Panditji which Panjika to use.

Comment: @Rickross thanks will surely look into it. I'd assume Dhanteras in general is good muhurta for financial investment, but need to confirm.